# Equivalent of isTextPresent of Selenium 1 (Selenium RC) in Selenium 2 (WebDriver)

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, assertion

There's no `isTextPresent` in Selenium 2 (WebDriver)

What is the correct way to assert the existence of some text on a page with WebDriver?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I normally do something along the lines of:

```
assertEquals(driver.getPageSource().contains("sometext"), true);

assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("sometext"));
```

Comment: This is good soltion, but it looks it is not the exact equivalent - look at the comments here: http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/03/moving-to-selenium-2-on-webdriver-part.html

Answer (score 5):

Page source contains HTML tags which might break your search text and result in false negatives. I found this solution works much like Selenium RC's isTextPresent API.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //or some other driver
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("Some text to search")
```

doing getText and then contains does have a performance trade-off. You might want to narrow down search tree by using a more specific WebElement.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but I found a good answer here: [Selenium 2.0 Web Driver: implementation of isTextPresent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7834791/162777)

In Python, this looks like:

```
def is_text_present(self, text):
    try: el = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
    return text in el.text
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you want to actually check the text content of a *WebElement* you could do something like:

```
assertEquals(getMyWebElement().getText(), "Expected text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium2 Java Code for isTextPresent (Selenium IDE Code) in JUnit4

```
public boolean isTextPresent(String str)
{
    WebElement bodyElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
    return bodyElement.getText().contains(str);
}

@Test
public void testText() throws Exception {
    assertTrue(isTextPresent("Some Text to search"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code using Java in WebDriver should work:

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Welcome Ripon Al Wasim"));
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("widget_205_after_login")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Welcome ripon[\\s\\S]*$"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written the following method:

```
public boolean isTextPresent(String text){
        try{
            boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains(text);
            return b;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The above method is called as below:

```
assertTrue(isTextPresent("some text"));
```

It is working nicely.

Comment: the assertTrue(boolean) and other assert methods are from JUnit ?I am assuming these are not with default java packages.

Comment: Don't you think there will be performance issue with "driver.getPageSource().contains(text)  ". I think it will search whole lot text of the page source. If that is the only way of doing to find a particular text then how do you justify the time elapse and code performance. Thank you for posting such a good question.

Comment: @MKod: I agree with you. It may cause performance issue as it searches whole text of a page. It needs to find out an alternative way(s). I guess WebDriver would be improved day by day

Comment: MKod: I used assertTrue(boolean) of TestNG. You can also use JUnit, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Testing if text is present in Ruby (a beginners approach) using firefox as target browser.

1) You need of course to download and run selenium server jar file with something like:

```
java - jar C:\Users\wmj\Downloads\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
```

2) You need to install ruby, and in its bin folder, run commands to install additional gems:

```
gem install selenium-webdriver
gem install test-unit
```

3) create a file test-it.rb containing:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

class TestIt < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def setup
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
        @base_url = "http://www.yoursitehere.com"
        @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
        @verification_errors = []
        @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new :timeout => 10
    end


    def teardown
        @driver.quit
        assert_equal [], @verification_errors
    end

    def element_present?(how, what)
        @driver.find_element(how, what)
        true
        rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
        false
    end

    def verify(&blk)
        yield
        rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
        @verification_errors << ex
    end

    def test_simple

        @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
        # simulate a click on a span that is contained in a "a href" link 
        @driver.find_element(:css, "#linkLogin > span").click
        # we clear username textbox
        @driver.find_element(:id, "UserName").clear
        # we enter username
        @driver.find_element(:id, "UserName").send_keys "bozo"
        # we clear password
        @driver.find_element(:id, "Password").clear
        # we enter password
        @driver.find_element(:id, "Password").send_keys "123456"
        # we click on a button where its css is named as "btn"
        @driver.find_element(:css, "input.btn").click

        # you can wait for page to load, to check if text "My account" is present in body tag
        assert_nothing_raised do
            @wait.until { @driver.find_element(:tag_name=>"body").text.include? "My account" }
        end
        # or you can use direct assertion to check if text "My account" is present in body tag
        assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("My account"),"My account text check!")

        @driver.find_element(:css, "input.btn").click
    end
end
```

4) run ruby:

```
ruby test-it.rb
```