# Selenium 2.0 Web Driver: implementation of isTextPresent

Tags: selenium, junit

I'm looking for a working implementation of this. The best I've come up with is:

```
    public boolean isTextPresent(String string) {

        for (WebElement e : drv.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"))) {

            if (e.isDisplayed() && e.getText().contains(string)) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can't be more specific when looking for the text? This is going to be slow as you're potentially walking the entire DOM. IE will be the worst.  It would be much better if you could at least narrow the search down some...

Comment: Naturally you're correct. I'm running there using Jenkins, so really time is less of an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A faster way to do it would be something like this:

```
public boolean isTextPresent(string str)
{
    IWebElement bodyElement = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
    return bodyElement.Text.contains(str);
}
```

It's in C# but it's the same concept. Getting the text of the body tag automatically returns the text of all the nested elements. The only thing I'm not sure about is if hidden elements are included or not.

Comment: Looks good. Would this capture invisible text too? E.g. JavaScript?

Comment: No, this will return the text visible on the screen, i.e. the inner text of elements. For example: <p>This text</p>.

Answer (score 0):

The following code using Java in WebDriver should work fine as isTextPresent:

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Welcome Ripon"));
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("widget_205_after_login")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Welcome ripon[\\s\\S]*$"));
```